# Swift Stripe Access DidCreateToken

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, token, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

---

I'm trying to integrate Stripe into my ios (`Swift`) app by using `Firebase-Cloud-Functions`. Now I'm want to get the token to a created card to save it into my `Firestore-Database`.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE) on how to implement it. It's working when I'm displaying my `addCardViewController` on my own since I have the method `didCreateToken`. But now that I'm just showing it `programmatically` like shown in their provided [example](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)/CheckoutViewController.swift) (row 158 is where they're showing the view controller) I don't know how to implement this method and get the token of the card `if a user creates/add`s a new one.

Thats what Id normally do:

```
func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock)
{
    STRIPE_CUSTOMERS_REF.document(userId).collection("tokens").addDocument(data: ["token": tokenId]) // Calls Firebase-Cloud-Function and adds payment method to Stripe
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

But like I said Im not able to implement this method.

I want to get the token when a user adds a new card.

Id really appreciates any kind of help. If you need any additional information let me know.

-Marie

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to save each individual card, instead of just charging their default card by creating a charge with their `cus_*` account token?

Comment: I don’t want the users to have to re-enter their credit card information every time they want to pay for something. If I misunderstood you let me know.

Comment: It's been a while, but if you use Stripe's default view controller for adding and choosing payment methods, then all you have to do is save the account token (the one that starts with `cus`), and instead of creating a charge with a card token, you would instead use the optional customer id field https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create. Stripe takes care of saving the details of every added card for you under the customer account, including whichever they choose to be the default. Sorry I can't provide more detail, again it's been a while.

Comment: To clarify, the first pictures at https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios are what I mean by Stripe's default view controller.

Comment: Thank you but I’m not trying to charge the user using this token. I just followed this tutorial: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE By saving the token the credit card gets saved onto my database aswell as stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you using `STPPaymentContext` (Standard Integration) to present the `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` (line 158 in the example above).

`STPPaymentContext` actually implements its own instances of `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` and `STPAddCardViewController`. Therefore, `STPPaymentContext` handles the delegate methods for those 2 view controllers and those aren't exposed to the user when using the Standard Integration. Which explains why that delegate method is not triggering for you.

Instead, your view controller should become the delegate for `STPPaymentContext` and implement the all the required delegate methods [0], including `paymentContextDidChange` method. 
`paymentContextDidChange` method is triggered whenever a user adds a new card or selects a new payment method [1].

When a user enters new card details, you should be able to get the token ID with the following:

```
func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext)
{
    if let card = paymentContext.selectedPaymentMethod as? STPCard {
        let token = card.stripeID
        // store token as required
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

[0] https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPPaymentContextDelegate.html

[1] https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPPaymentMethod.html

Comment: Thank you, but that only gives me the cardId and not the token. (Card_73737372 and Not tok_73737)

Comment: When using `STPPaymentContext`, you are returned an object of type `STPPaymentResult`. This represents an `STPCard` or a Card object [0]. Card objects are similar to token objects but are associated to a particular Customer. You can create charges using Card objects.
`STPAddCardViewController` can be used to obtain STPToken object.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards

Comment: And is it possible to get the token the way I’m doing it right now or would I have to implement the custom integration?

Comment: You would get an STPCard object, which, like a token, can be used to create a charge. However, if you are looking to get just an STPToken object, then you would have to implement the custom integration.